# Postgresql - Avg just minutes and seconds?

Tags: postgresql

Im running an aggregate query that's returning just two columns, a `name` and `timez`.

`timez` is currently in the format of `MI:SS`, stored as varchar. In my query, I want to get the average minutes and seconds of `time`, but of course if I cast the column to a timestamp, the `avg()` function doesn't work on it. I tried dividing the timestamps by count(1) which doesn't work either as timestamps can't be divided. Below is what I ideally wanted.

```
SELECT name, avg(to_timestamp(timez,'MI:SS'))
FROM logs_table
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast the `timez` column to a `time` type before applying `avg`:

```
SELECT name, avg(CAST(timez AS time))
FROM logs_table
GROUP BY name;
```